# Is the "object sender, EventArgs e" event handler signature just a convention?

Tags: c#, events

The traditional way to declaring an event is to create a custom args class by extending from EventArgs:

```
public class SomethingHappenedEventArgs : EventArgs
```

Then take that and a reference to the object declaring the event into the handler:

```
public SomethingHappenedHandler(object sender, SomethingHappenedEventArgs e)
```

But, of course, you don't *have* to do this. Your event handler delete can have any method signature you like.

So, is the "object, EventArgs" signature just convention?  Is it out-dated?  Or are there clear technical advantages to it that I'm not understanding?

Comment: Yes, its a convention, however it has distinct advantages in that the handler doesn't need to use some stored-elsewhere instance of the sender, the sender is passed in. This is useful if a single method handles multiple events and senders. Also there is an easy way to declare the event, you just use `public event EventHandler<SomethingHappenedEventArgs> SomethingHappened`, and that sets up the delegate signature for you.

Comment: It is most definitely more than a convention.  This was *very* carefully thought about.  For a very long time, well before .NET came around.  Anders Hejlsberg brought it with him.  Core ideas were to make an event handler usable for multiple events (thus sender) and significantly reduce the pain of refactoring (thus EventArgs inheritance).  Also the notion of events having info that is only valid while the event is raised and mutates later (thus e vs properties).

Comment: It is a convention. The only advantage is that delegates are covariant so that a less derived handler can handler a more derived event. I think it is also outdated as we now have generics so using plain `object` seems like a OOP anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is Convention.**

[Events Tutorial (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx)

> Although the C# language allows events to use any delegate type, the
>   .NET Framework has some stricter guidelines on the delegate types that
>   should be used for events.
>   The .NET Framework guidelines indicate that the delegate type used for
>   an event should take two parameters, an "object source" parameter
>   indicating the source of the event, and an "e" parameter that
>   encapsulates any additional information about the event. The type of
>   the "e" parameter should derive from the EventArgs class. For events
>   that do not use any additional information, the .NET Framework has
>   already defined an appropriate delegate type: EventHandler.

[Events, Delegates, and CLR Event System Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833085(v=vs.95).aspx)

> By convention, event delegates in the .NET Framework have two
>   parameters, the source that raised the event, represented by the
>   sender parameter, and the data for the event, represented by the e
>   parameter.

**It is not out-dated.**

[Handling and Raising Events (.NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The EventArgs class is the base type for all event data classes.
>   EventArgs is also the class you use when an event does not have any
>   data associated with it. When you create an event that is only meant
>   to notify other classes that something happened and does not need to
>   pass any data, include the EventArgs class as the second parameter in
>   the delegate. You can pass the EventArgs.Empty value when no data is
>   provided. The EventHandler delegate includes the EventArgs class as a
>   parameter.